# Can a native IE7 handle the IE8 document mode?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I'm having some trouble, as usual, with making my html and jquery work on IE7.
I got no problems when i set the document mode in the developer tools to IE8-Standards, using IE7 as browser mode, but i don't know if a native IE7 can do the same.
Has anyone got experience using this mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, IE 7 does not support rendering pages like IE 8.

That would require a time machine. IE 8 and its "standards mode" hadn't been invented at the time that IE 7 was released.

Comment: thank you. just thought maybe an update would eventually have caused ie7 to know the docmode of ie8.

Comment: @fischi Unfortunately, no. The update that Microsoft would push out to IE 7 users would be IE 8. It's supported on every machine that IE 7 is, so there's really no good reason for people to still be running IE 7. Before investing *too* much time into customizing your site to work with IE 7, consider if it's really necessary.